# The system network services are not compatible with this version Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: network-manager

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on my PC. I have created some new accounts and then after I logged in to my own account there was no internet connection. When I try to open the network settings I faced this error

```
The system network services are not compatible with this version.
```

I have tried starting the NetworkManager manually with this command

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

but it has not worked.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 11):

Network Manager Crash on ubuntu 14.04

After upgrade from proposed repository the next packages:  `libnl-3-200, libnl-genl-3-200 and libnl-route-3-200`.

You'll need to downgrade your libnl-3 packages:

```
sudo apt-get install libnl-3-200=3.2.21-1 libnl-genl-3-200=3.2.21-1 \ 
libnl-route-3-200=3.2.21-1
```

if you can not install these packages or have trouble making the downgrade you can manually download them from here(from my account):

https://mega.nz/#F!7kchgI7Z!U5Y_M80OSSS5DZKfZGrC3g

Steps:

1. Download the 3 files on another computer.
2. Copy them to a flashdrive.
3. Put the flashdrive in to the affected computer.
4. Copy the 3 files into a new folder.
5. Open a terminal in that folder and run

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i lib*.deb
   sudo reboot
   ```

   And you may need to apply a hold until a fix for NetworkManager can be released.

   ```
   sudo apt-mark hold libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200
   ```

   And after the fix:

   ```
   sudo apt-mark auto libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200
   ```

More info:

Comment: link not working, is there any other place to use for download?

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libnl-3-200

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1539634

Comment: sudo apt-mark unhold libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200

Comment: I solved the problem following @Paul Iulian answer, and downloading the file from the link provided by user309383. Thanks for your help. However, I have two questions. 
1) At the link provided I could only download one file: libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb, and not 3 as I expected. However, things worked. Am I supposed to find other files?
2) About applying the hold: How will I know a fix has been released?
Appreciate a lot your help.

Comment: Solved my problem 1). The libnl-genl and libnl-route files are respectively http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libnl-genl-3-200 and http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libnl-route-3-200.
I would still appreciate a comment on my question 2).

Comment: Had the same issue and the solution worked like a charm!!
Downloaded the files from:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libnl-3-200, 
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libnl-genl-3-200, 
http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libnl-route-3-200 
and went for "amd64" deb files for my 64bit Intel machine.

Comment: How will you get to know, that when to remove the hold?

Answer (score 0):

This error message is generally related to bad `/etc/network/interfaces` file.
Try following

```
sudo cp /etc/network/interfaces /etc/network/interfaces.bak
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Remove everything from the file and put

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Then reboot the system. It should work.

Comment: that's exactly content of my copy of this file after update but the issue remains

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Seems that a recent update is the cause. Lots of messages in the syslog for network-manager being killed by segv (segmentation fault) signal. I believe the update for network manager has a segmentation violation bug somewhere.

I managed to resolve my issue using the advice given by Paul Iulian. The link in his post does not work, so I downloaded the packages from
http://packages.ubuntu.com/

Search for the names of the packages libnl-3-200, libnl-genl-3-200 and libnl-route-3-200

Regards, Jordan.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this in your terminal

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up // Make your interface up
sudo dhclient  // assign Ipaddress by dhcp
sudo apt-get install network-manager // Now install latest network-manager
sudo service network-manager restart //restart network-manager
```

after your try it, update you network manager.

Comment: Please  [edit] your answer with what the code does and why it may work. Just telling someone a terminal code is not a valid answer.

Comment: To piggyback off of @DnrDevil's comment: Just providing code is a really bad idea as it *could* be malicious/wrong. It's always best to explain what that command does, and why.

Comment: tried... have an idea what it does... not working because network services are not working :)