# "The system network services are not compatible with this version" - ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager

"The system network services are not compatible with this version" - ubuntu 14.04... I didn't even update anything thing.I have everything in network manager ....and I'm unable to connect to any network.. my system is dumb now without any network.
I just tried to delete the previously connected networks from system-connections.. i tried the following code(I found it on askubuntu.com):

**nmcli --fields UUID,TIMESTAMP-REAL con show | grep never |  awk '{print $1}' | while read line; do nmcli con delete uuid  $line;    done**

[this link didn't solve my problem with the same title](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727188/the-system-network-services-are-not-compatible-with-this-version-ubuntu-14-04)

Please help me and know that I'm not connected to a network.so help me in downloading external packages... and gracious!

**none of the links on the askubuntu.com helped me!**   is there any possibility so I can download and reinstall some softwares!!!

[image]

Comment: confirming that this problem is still happening, many months after the OP.  I keep my machine up-to-date and don't have pre-package releases selected in my update manager.  Ugh.

Answer (score 10):

http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/

Go to the above mentioned address and download three .deb files

libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb

this is for 64bit OS
for 32bit use i386.deb

( please confirm your OS whether 32bit or 64bit)

Place them in a new folder on desktop and name the folder abc.
Enter into it through terminal cd desktop abc
and do  "sudo dpkg -i filename.deb" for all the three.
Restart the system, you will get the network tab and its details on the top to access.

I had the same problem yesterday after updating the system.
I tried this it worked.

---

Comment: Thank you very much and this really worked for me too...!

Comment: I can confirm that it worked for me too. Thank you so much **Prasad G R**, it was really very frustrating to see this issue when I start my notebook despite that **there was no any other installation than official software updates.**

Comment: Worked for me on 5/13/2016.  Notice that it DOWNGRADES components, which makes me worried for the future.  Still fixed for now.  Massive relief!

Comment: Just used it and worked for me. I'm a bit scared too that this "old" solution could bring collateral bad effects

Answer (score 3):

After a long research on this problem I'm deducting these possibilities:

**Causes of the problem:**

1) Incomplete installation.
2) Pre-released software might end up in causing so un-select it in software manager settings.

**Solution :** 
1)Restart the network Manager.
  `sudo service network-manager start`

if this isn't work in your case download the following files manually from other pc and copy it to affected system.
[Click here to get those files.](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libn/libnl3/) 
For 64 bit :

1. libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
2. libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
3. libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb

For 32 bit:
 1. libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1_i386.deb.deb
 2. libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_i386.deb.deb
 3. libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1_i386.deb.deb
Put them in a folder and in terminal go up to that terminal,these are Debian files so install using this command.

`sudo dpkg -i lib*.deb`

this will install all three files at a time. And now restart your system. Every thing works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I have the identical problem.. it occurred after an update in my case.. it no longer has the icon top right for wi-fi networks.. i suspect the wired NIC and wi-fi card ought to appear in the list (above picture) below Network Proxy but can't be sure.. never really looked there before i had a problem!