# Re-Installing Network Manager via Live USB?

Tags: networking, network-manager

I don't know what happened, but when I got back from suspend, suddenly network manager was deleted on my ubuntu 14.04. So, looks like it needs a reinstall, however, I don't have the packages saved anymore.

I did find the following page that probably would solve my problem:

[How to reinstall network manager without internet access?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422928/how-to-reinstall-network-manager-without-internet-access)

Only, there is a stumbling block: I can't open/edit `/etc/resolv.conf`.

My steps:

```
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
xubuntu@xubuntu:~$ sudo chroot /mnt
root@xubuntu:/# sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /sda2/etc/resolv.conf
sudo: unable to resolve host xubuntu
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/sda2/etc/resolv.conf’: No such file or directory
root@xubuntu:/#
```

And if I try to edit via nano, the file that gets opened is  `File: /var/tmp/resolvXX5eDVsN.conf`

What obvious mistake am I making here? Because I just don't see it. Anyone who will please help me?

Comment: Problem not solved. Apparently network manager is still installed, but even though I restarted it like Sai Teja suggested, I get the message that it's running and a process number that I  can't see in system manager under all processes. And resolv.conf gets emptied after each restart. I'm confused. How do I solve this? And Sai, the libs you said to download. Did you mean by that I should downgrade? Because according to symantic I already have the latest versions of them.

Comment: Okay, still no idea what's going on with network-manager, but I  deinstallieren it, downloaded wicd instead. That works as far as internet connection goes.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening for others also in this week...After a long research on this problem I'm deducting these possibilities:

Causes of the problem:

1) Incomplete installation. 2) Pre-released software might end up in causing so un-select it in software manager settings.

Solution : 1)Restart the network Manager. `sudo service network-manager start`

if this isn't work in your case download the following files manually from other pc and copy it to affected system. Click here to get those files. For 64 bit :

```
libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
```

For 32 bit: 1. libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1_i386.deb.deb
2. libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_i386.deb.deb
3. libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1_i386.deb.deb Put them in a folder and in terminal go up to that terminal,these are Debian files so install using this command.

`sudo dpkg -i lib*.deb`

this will install all three files at a time. And now restart your system. Every thing works fine your network manager will come again! [the actual link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727988/the-system-network-services-are-not-compatible-with-this-version-ubuntu-14-0/728867#728867)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try. The problem is, I've been using 14.04 for a long time now, and it's only now this is happening, so it's unlikely to be incomplete installation.  Maybe the second one? Can't say.

Comment: Jacob, how do you figure my question a duplication? Yes, the underlying problem might be, I've even pointed to a possible solution from this site itself. But my main question was what I was doing wrong with the resolv.conf edit.

Comment: @deniz For the record, I didn't mark it as a dupe, but you're right, I acted by *the answer*, which does not make the dupe.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious mistake you made was mixing you mount point with the name of your block device. You can't do:

```
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /sda2/etc/resolv.conf
```

because `/sda2` is non-existing directory. Earlier you did:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

and `/mnt` (not `/sda2`) is the right directory for your copy operations. So do:

```
sudo cp /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: Thank you! Knew I wasn't seeing the obvious. Let's see if it works. :-)