# The system network services are not compatible with this version Ubuntu 14.04 problem to degradate libnl

Tags: network-manager, dpkg

After command: `sudo dpkg -i lib*.deb`

For files:

```
libnl-route-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
libnl-genl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
libnl-3-200-dbg_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb
```

I had a problem:

```
dpkg: error processing package libnl-3-200-dbg (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnl-genl-3-200:amd64:
 libnl-genl-3-200:amd64 depends on libnl-3-200 (= 3.2.21-1); however:
  Version of libnl-3-200:amd64 on system is 3.2.21-1ubuntu1.

dpkg: error processing package libnl-genl-3-200:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libnl-route-3-200:amd64:
 libnl-route-3-200:amd64 depends on libnl-3-200 (= 3.2.21-1); however:
  Version of libnl-3-200:amd64 on system is 3.2.21-1ubuntu1.
```

Even if I try to remove libnl before install:

```
$ sudo dpkg -r libnl-genl-3-200:amd64
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libnl-genl-3-200:amd64:
 network-manager depends on libnl-genl-3-200 (>= 3.2.7).
 crda depends on libnl-genl-3-200 (>= 3.2.7).
 plainbox-provider-resource-generic depends on libnl-genl-3-200 (>= 3.2.7).
 iw depends on libnl-genl-3-200 (>= 3.2.3).
 wpasupplicant depends on libnl-genl-3-200 (>= 3.2.7).

dpkg: error processing package libnl-genl-3-200:amd64 (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libnl-genl-3-200:amd64
```

Please help!

Solution from here - ["The system network services are not compatible with this version" - ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727988/the-system-network-services-are-not-compatible-with-this-version-ubuntu-14-0/728728#728728)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue with a VMware guest.  The root cause is that I had the trusty-proposed repository enabled.  I personally won't do that again.  My resolution was to re-install.  An option I took as it was a test virtual.  As I understand it, a fix for a physical machine would be to sneakernet across the previous deb files to roll back the upgrade that broke your networking and sudo dpkg -i to install them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `libnl-3-200_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb`, not `libnl-3-200-dbg_3.2.21-1_amd64.deb` (note the additional **`-dbg`**) to perform the [recommended fix](/questions/727988/the-system-network-services-are-not-compatible-with-this-version-ubuntu-14-0/728728#728728). Please verify that you downloaded the correct package files, delete unrequired package files, and try again.