# How to fix/repair/remove/disable/install/uninstall 'Broken Packages' on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, networking, package-management, updates, dependencies

I'm using a machine that runs on **64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS**

I run regular 'System Updates'. On one day after performing such regular 'System Update' my system stopped detecting wireless and wired networks. Then I followed the steps given in following question :
[Did the steps to enable wireless and wired network detection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727188/the-system-network-services-are-not-compatible-with-this-version-ubuntu-14-04)

My wi-fi and wired network got started working but one red circular icon containing minus sign within started appearing on system tray at top right corner of my screen.

When I clicked on it, a pop-up appeared. From it I chose the option'Install all updates'. Then following pop-up appeared.

[image: Then following pop-up appeared.]

Now can someone please help me in running my system smoothly with all the updated packages and get rid off the red circular icon appearing in a system tray?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First tidy your repository with `sudo apt-get autoremove` then `sudo apt-get update` Then sort your problem with `sudo apt-get install -f`