# The system network services are not compatible with this version. Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on my PC, Kernel 3.13.0.135-generic.
After grub crash and system upgrade I have got the above message and no network.

I tried the solution described here:
[The system network services are not compatible with this version Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/727188/the-system-network-services-are-not-compatible-with-this-version-ubuntu-14-04)

In recovery mode I succeed in downloading and downgrading the packages libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200, but this did not help (((

Any other ideas?

Comment: I succeed in manual LAN configuration via /etc/network/interfaces, but the above problem still persists.
I've tried: `code` apt-get install network-manager `\code`, but it says, that network-manager is already the latest version, but

Comment: "sudo service network-manager restart' returns "network-manager: unrecognized service". The same result for "sudo service NetworkManager restart"

Answer (score 0):

The reason was in absent config file. It was renamed to "network-manager.conf.orig". After removing ".orig" from the name - network manager starts normally.